# Преобразовать прописные буквы в строчные

Tags: c#

> В заданном тексте, после первого схождения символа "@" преобразовать строчные буквы а прописные.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Согласен с комментарием выше, сначала необходимо самим попробовать поискать методы решения, а потом обращаться сюда с конкретным вопросам. Советую посмотреть на такие методы как `.replace()` `.substring()` и `.indexOf()`

Comment: @TiiRiiX  я вообще не шарю в с# но вижу что в javascript и в php одинаково, интересно  почему ?

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста:

```
string text = "В заданном тексте, после первого схождения символа @ преобразовать строчные буквы а прописные.";
string result = string.Concat(text.TakeWhile(c => c != '@').Concat(text.SkipWhile(c => c != '@').Select(char.ToUpper)));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Вывод:

```
В заданном тексте, после первого схождения символа @ ПРЕОБРАЗОВАТЬ СТРОЧНЫЕ БУКВЫ А ПРОПИСНЫЕ.
```